# Maybe the bucket is owned by somebody else or the authentication failed while Wildfly Starting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, wildfly

I have setup an clustered environment with Wildfly 10 on AWS. This is the configuration I have done for this job;

```
...
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:4.0">
<channels default="ee">
    <channel name="ee" stack="s3ping"/>
<channels>
<stacks>
       ...            
    <stack name="s3ping">
       <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp" diagnostics-socket-binding="jgroups-diagnostics"/>
           <protocol type="S3_PING">
               <property name="access_key">
                   <%= @s3_access_key %>
               </property>
               <property name="secret_access_key">
                   <%= @s3_secret_access_key %>
               </property>
               <property name="prefix">
                   <%= @s3_bucket %>
               </property>
               <property name="timeout">
                   60000
               </property>
           </protocol>
           <protocol type="MERGE2"/>
           <protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp-fd"/>              
           <protocol type="FD"/>
           <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
           <protocol type="BARRIER"/>
           <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK"/>
           <protocol type="UNICAST2"/>
           <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
           <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
           <protocol type="UFC"/>
           <protocol type="MFC"/>
           <protocol type="FRAG2"/>
       </stack>
</stacks>
</subsystem>
...
```

If I give a bucket name that is not exist, the system creates a bucket on s3 on US Standard region.

But I want it to be in eu-central.

So I have create a bucket on AWS Console and set its policy as

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "[USERARN]"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[BUCKETNAME]/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "[USERARN]"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[BUCKETNAME]"
    }
]
}
```

and given created bucket name to stanalone-ha.xml.

But this time while Wildfly staring it throws

```
Maybe the bucket is owned by somebody else or the authentication failed.
```

exception.

What is my mistake and what can I do to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Only one bucket of a given name can exist *anywhere, in any region* of S3 (the bucket namespace is global).  If you already created `example-bucket` in US Standard, you'll need to go to the console and delete it, then wait a few minutes before trying to create a bucket of the exact same name in any other region.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: I know that and it is not the problem. I create bucket successfully and after that I start wildfly

Comment: Oh, yes, I see now, you already created it in the correct place in the console.

Comment: What can else be the problem, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a comman issue.

My bucket is at Frankfurt region and S3 Ping does not work on Frankfurt region because S3 Ping uses AWS Authentication V2 but Frankfurt region requires AWS Authentication V4.

related info: issues.jboss.org/browse/JGRP-1914